# Use appguid if available otherwise use hardcoded guid in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, active-directory

How can I write below lambda expression so it can check for a matching appguid and if it won't find any, then it will look for hardcoded guid instead?

```
public static string ActiveDirectory(string xmlPath, string applicationGUID,string Element)
{
    XDocument dbConfig = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

    return (dbConfig
                     .Descendants("Zone")
                     .Where(a =>
                     {
                         XElement ag = a.Element("ApplicationGUID");
                         return ag != null &&
                                (ag.Value == applicationGUID || ag.Value == "3773e594efga42688cd5113cf316d4d3");
                     })
                     .Select(
                         a =>
                         {
                             XElement cs = a.Element(Element);
                             return cs == null
                                        ? null
                                        : cs.Value;
                         })
                     .SingleOrDefault());
}
```

This is how my xml look like

```
<Zone>

        <ApplicationGUID>69b150127e7d43efa0e3e896b94953de</ApplicationGUID>
        <isActiveDirectory>true</isActiveDirectory>
        <ActiveDirectoryPath>LDAP://test.org</ActiveDirectoryPath>
        <DomainName>test1</DomainName>
    </Zone>
  <Zone>
           <ApplicationGUID>3773e594efga42688cd5113cf316d4d3</ApplicationGUID>
    <!--Default App guid-->
    <isActiveDirectory>true</isActiveDirectory>
    <ActiveDirectoryPath>LDAP://test.org</ActiveDirectoryPath>
    <DomainName>test2</DomainName>
  </Zone>
</Zones>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've posted?

Comment: Its giving me an error if my xml file have matching appguid and also hardcoded guid in it. I want to check for matching appguid first and if there is no matching appguid then only look for hardcoded.

Comment: Maybe give an example of the data producing the error and the actual error you're receivng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default back with a second query, such as...

```
public static string ActiveDirectory(string xmlPath, string applicationGUID, string Element)
{
    XDocument dbConfig = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

    var ret = (dbConfig
                     .Descendants("Zone")
                     .Where(a =>
                     {
                         XElement ag =
                             a.Element("ApplicationGUID");

                         return ag != null &&
                                (ag.Value == applicationGUID);
                     })
                     .SingleOrDefault());

    if(ret == null)
       ret = (dbConfig
                     .Descendants("Zone")
                     .Where(a =>
                     {
                         XElement ag =
                             a.Element("ApplicationGUID");

                         return ag != null &&
                                (ag.Value == "3773e594efga42688cd5113cf316d4d3");
                     })
                     .SingleOrDefault());

    if(ret != null)
    {
           XElement cs = ret.Element(Element);

           return cs == null ? null : cs.Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

You could do it with trickery to make it a single statement, but why obfuscate the statement.  Assuming your XML isn't very long and that this function isn't called over and over, this will likely not be your bottleneck, all while resulting in easier to read and understand code.

However, if you really want just one statement, then you could try using `OrderBy` to set a priority, such as:

```
public static string ActiveDirectory(string xmlPath, string applicationGUID,string Element)
{
XDocument dbConfig = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

return (dbConfig
                 .Descendants("Zone")
                 .Where(a =>
                 {
                     XElement ag =
                         a.Element("ApplicationGUID");

                     return ag != null &&
                            (ag.Value == applicationGUID || ag.Value == "3773e594efga42688cd5113cf316d4d3");
                 })
                 .OrderBy(a => a.Element("ApplicationGUID").Value == "3773e594efga42688cd5113cf316d4d3" ? 1 : 0)
                 .Select(
                     a =>
                     {
                         XElement cs =
                             a.Element(Element);

                         return cs == null
                                    ? null
                                    : cs.Value;
                     })
                 .FirstOrDefault());
}
```

This `OrderBy` gives ordering priority where the Guid wasn't the static one, then using `FirstOrDefault` to get the highest priority match, which woudl be the case where `ag.Value == applicationGuid`.  Notice I don't make sure `a.Element(...)` isn't null first because my `Where` above it will filter any out where it is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `SingleOrDefault()` at the end of your statement. In your example data, you have two matches to the `Where()` Func provided. `SingleOrDefault` returns a single member if there is a single match, the default of the return type if there are no matches, or throws an exception. In your case, two matches, thus an exception.

The easiest solution to what it looks like you're trying to do would be to just run two queries. First check if the passed ID has a match, if it doesn't, look for a match with your hard coded value.